# My view is not loading onload. angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, uiview, angular-ui-router

Iam developing a webapp using angular as frontend. Iam strictly adhering to SPA concept. I have included two files with ng-include directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-if="!isLoggedIn">
        <!-- Should include MAININDEX.HTML here.........--->
        <div ng-include="'templates/mainindex.html'"></div>

    </div>

    <div ng-if="isLoggedIn">
        <!-- Should include MAINLOGGEDIN.HTML here.........--->
        <div ng-include="'templates/mainloggedin.html'"></div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Once i logged in the second div will be showed. It is working perfectly but on my load of second div i wish to display a ui-view in that partials like below.

```
<!----Header bar, Side bar, Navigation bar code goes here--->
<section class="content-wrapper">

    <div ui-view=""></div>

</section>
<!--footer bar code here--->
```

My header bar and footer bar loads clearly as soon as my login is sucessfull but my ui-view is not loading up. I wish my home route to be loaded initially. But it is blank and i have to click someother route and then click the home to display it in my UI-View portion. My state routing code goes like this.....

```
// For any unmatched url, redirect to /state1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
//
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('index', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        resolve: {

            loggedin: checkLoggedin
        }

    })
```

am i going wrong some where. Is my url routing goes fine.

Comment: You can try to create a Plunker. In 90% of cases, when I want to ask a question, I found the solution while writing a Plunker.

Comment: that was good thing to know let me learn creating a plunker~~~~!